# Jquery Draggable + Bring to Front

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a window with a number of chat DIV's where a user to chat to different people.

Currently the chat DIV's can be open and moved around but I can't see to get the currently select DIV to set at the front. eg: when you mousedown on a DIV it comes into the foreground.

HTML:

```
<div id="1000000001" class="chatMessenger">
    <div class="chatMessengerContainer">
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.chatMessenger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
    // JQUERY UI Draggable - Initialize
    $('div#'+memberID).draggable({
        containment: $('div#chatWrapper')
    });


    // JQUERY UI Draggable - Setting the Stack
    $(document).on('mousedown','div.chatMessenger', function() {
        alert('chat mouse down...');
        //var stack = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "stack" );
        $(this).draggable( "option", "stack", ".products" );
    });
```

The alert triggers in the mousedown so this is finding the correct element.

I have looked at Draggable z-index and stack but I was unable to get either working.

There will be many chat DIV's open at the same time to the selected one needs to sit at the front.

thankyou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should help

```
$('div.chatMessenger').not(this).css('z-index', '100');
$(this).css('z-index', '1000');
```

inside `on('mousedown')` function.

Answer (score 2):

For several draggables where you want to bring one to front and reset others to back:

```
$('.container').on('mousedown', function(event) { 
    $('.container').css('z-index','1');
    $( this ).css('z-index','1000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the easiest implementation is to move the div in the dom to the last position. so if you dont have to care about the position in the dom this is the easiest way without using z-index.
i use this for positioning some sticky notes.

```
$("#chatWrapper").on('mousedown', '.chatMessenger', function() {
    $(this).appendTo("#chatWrapper");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there is an option - 'stack' existing while initiating draggables
like this -

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    stack: ".draggable"
});
```

But it is not working properly, So I have wrote a small library dragToFront playing with z-index. Following is the plunkr link

https://embed.plnkr.co/mJqkxSJhf1Umg7r2oLQN/

Comment: Your library is working like a charm but the use of ctr variable makes it limited, for example your library won't work if there is a pre loaded draggable divs