# Jquery + zindex increment

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Draggable + Bring to Front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665435/jquery-draggable-bring-to-front)

I have a site where users can open a number of chat windows.

I need to keep the latest window on top and I'm using the following

```
        var chatZIndex = 100;   
        $(document).on('mousedown','div.chatMessenger', function() {
            $(this).css('z-index', chatZIndex++);
        });
```

This works fine but I have found one bug. If there are 6 chat boxes open (6 instances of 'div.chatMessenger') then the variable chatZIndex increments by 6 at a time. 4 open and then increments by 4 etc etc.

Is there a way to use this same setup but only have the variable increment by 1 at a time regardless of how many instances of 'div.chatMessenger' are open?

thx

---

this is the current code to set them up

```
var memberID = 1000000000;          // This is the Member ID - REPLACE
var chatMsgTop = 45;                        // Initial Chat Open Location Top
var chatMsgLeft = 45;                       // Initial Chat Open Location Left
var chatZIndex = 100;                       // Starting Number for Chat Messenger z-index Value

// Chat Messenger - Open a New Chat Messager IM Box
$(document).on('click','div#chatFriendsContainer table tr', function() {

    memberID++;     // This is the Member ID - REPLACE

    // Increment Initial Chat Messaging Location on Windows - Avoid Overlap
    chatMsgTop += 10;
    chatMsgLeft += 10;

    var timeStamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);                                                                                                                          // Timestamp
    $('div#chatWrapper').append('<div id="'+memberID+'" class="chatMessenger" data-timestamp="'+timeStamp+'"></div>');          // Create new Chat IM Container
    $('div#chatMessengerTemplate div.chatMessengerContainer').clone().appendTo('div#'+memberID);                                                        // Clone Template
    $('div#'+memberID).css({left : chatMsgLeft+'px', top : chatMsgTop+'px'});                                                                                               // Update IM Location


    // JQUERY UI Draggable - Initialize
    $('div#'+memberID).draggable({
        containment: $('div#chatWrapper')
    });


    // JQUERY UI Draggable - Update Z-Index
    $(document).on('mousedown','div.chatMessenger', function() {
        //$('div.chatMessenger').not(this).css('z-index', '100');
        //alert('here now...');

        if($('div.chatMessenger', this)) {
            $(this).css('z-index', chatZIndex++);
        }


    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665435/jquery-draggable-bring-to-front/12665480#12665480 i happened to see the same question from you yesterday

Comment: yes but the problem with this solution is that when you open the chat boxes in an order and then start clicking on individual boxes sometimes depending on the order boxes will switch behind otherwise if they were opened later. I know this isn't explained well but its a bit buggy...

Comment: move the code block under // JQUERY UI Draggable - Update Z-Index  outside of the // Chat Messenger - Open a New Chat Messager IM Box block -  you are attaching a new eventhandler every time a click on div#chatFriendsContainer occurs. thats why your z index increases by #ammount clicked on div#chatFriendsContainer

Comment: supernova... thankyou so much... So obvious now I see it... really appreciate your time... thanks...!!!

Comment: you're welcome, but could have let me post that as answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're adding 2 mousedown callback to newly created ones so it duplicates the adding of variables ++.

Can you supply more code that we can examine?
Will update my answer below to your additional code later

How about using the .index()

http://api.jquery.com/index/

or using the bind method to ensure it's only done once

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're not creating your new chat windows properly. Your code should work properly if you have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thetext/VT8j8/. - Your chat elements are all siblings.

But instead I think you have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thetext/F84Aa/. - your chat elements are nested within the previous one.

Comment: I hear you but they all reside at the same level. Note: I get the same increment regardless of which one I click on. In your example the higher up ones increment by less... thanks so much for the idea...

Answer (score 0):

this uses the data element of the 'on' functionality

```
var chatZIndex = 100;  
$("body").on({"mousedown":function(event){
  $(this).css('z-index',chatZIndex ).trigger("upZIndex");

},"upZIndex":function(event){
  chatZindex++;
}},"div.chatMessenger",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class like active-chat with much higher z-index than div.chatMessenger

```
​$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.chatMessenger').click(function(){

        // Find The Current Active Chat Window Then REmove The Class
        $('.active-chat').removeClass('active-chat');
        // Assign THe active-chat class to the clicked div
        $(this).addClass('active-chat');  

    });

});​
```